# Video playing from the host so it doesn't start from the beginning when reloading

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, video

Is it possible to have for example a video playing from the host server, so when someone is going on my website the video is instead of starting at 0:00, at that point where it is on the host server. What I'm trying to say is that the video is always synchronized with the one on the server so even if I reload the site its still synchronized and not starting from the beginning. It's hard to explain because my English is not that good. I hope you understand the issue I'm having
Thanks

Comment: Store the time in a session or cookie then play it from that point.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: I was just asking. I have no clue how to work with cookies or sessions

Comment: Cookies and sessions actually do nothing for what he wants to do.

Comment: Then just do math to determine where the Video starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you save your video? Do you have any place to put additional infos like the point your video is at? If not, you will probably have to use a defined starting point in time and then calculate at what time it should currently be. (like

```
$start = time() - $starttime;  //uses unix timestamps
$start = $start % $lengthOfVideo;
```

You will then have to manually set the values for `$starttime` and `$lengthOfVideo`. The former should be any point in time on which the video will start at 0:00. `$lengthOfVideo`is the length of the desired video in seconds.

How to start the video at a special time depends again on the way you have saved your video and what player you use. Youtube for instance let's you encode the starting time in it's url.

Comment: The video was just an example otherwise it would be to hard to explain but thank you i think i know how to do it now in my case